# Android raw resource

Tags: android

I have some sql queries that I would like to put in a `.txt` file and import to my application on start up. 2 questions:

1) Where is the best place to put these files?

2) I thought maybe I can put them in `/res/raw/sql/` but the files don't come up with AutoComplete. (They come up if I put them in `/res/raw/`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make sub folders of the resources folder Android provides per default. The same is true for the various layout folders etc. So you have to put them directly in `/res/raw.` But anyway, I think there it is the best place to save them.